# On the Group of order $pq$ where $p , q $ are primes .

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a group, $\lvert G \rvert = pq$ where $p$, $q$ are primes, $q$ is bigger than $p$.

Let $P$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup and $Q$ be a Sylow $q$-subgroup 
and let $n_p$= the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups.
Prove that $n_p$ divides $q$, $n_q$ divides $p$

---

This fact is used in proving some statements in Dummit and Foote, page 143, 3rd ed, but I don't know why is it true, so I post my question.

Comment: Read *and understand* Theorem 18, page 139, in D&F

Answer (score 1):

Quick "answer", which must be obvious if you really read that theorem in page 143 in D&F, which is not other than Sylow's Theorem.

In this theorem's proof one sees that if $\,|G|=p^\alpha m\,\, ,\,\, p^{\alpha+1}\nmid|G|\,$ , then in fact, if $\,P\,$ is *any* Sylow $\,p-$Sylow subgroup of $\,G\,$ , we get

$$n_p=[G:N_G(P)]=1\pmod p\Longrightarrow n_p\mid m$$

Comment: @amWhy , what does " leading a horse to water " mean ?

Comment: MrWhy: I was just hoping that the answer would provide the help you need for answering the question, that's all!